# Does WordPress Development Mode Exist (with not minified JS)?

Tags: functions, javascript

A lot of WP JS is minified and therefore it's hard to be analyzed in the Console. Is there any way to have all scripts uncompressed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is, from [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#SCRIPT_DEBUG) codex, you need to define `SCRIPT_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php` to force WP to load the `dev` versions of the scripts:

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: but this works only, if the script is in readable form inside the plugin or theme. If is not, then use the button on Webinspector in Chrome and create with one click a readable form.

Comment: Keep in mind that while core WordPress includes these dev versions of scripts, not all plugins or themes do.

Comment: Thanks! I'm only interested in WP dev versions of scripts :)

Comment: Also there is no non-minified version of backbone.js for some reason.

Comment: Apparently core devs [don't want to increase core size](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32358#comment:14) by adding unminified js files into core